# CKEditor not working

Tags: ckeditor

I just downloaded CKEditor to use the WYSIWYG editor on my website, but this code:

```
<div id="editor">
This is a test
</div>
<script>
    CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor' );
</script>
```

Or this code:

```
<textarea id="editor">
this is a test
</textarea>
<script>
    CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor' );
</script>
```

Is only making the div and the textarea hide, no WYSIWYG editor is being shown.

The sample page is working and for my page the CSS and JS are both loaded.

What can be the problem?

Edit:

When I use their example code (stated here: http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_installation)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>A Simple Page with CKEditor</title>
        <!-- Make sure the path to CKEditor is correct. -->
        <script src="../ckeditor.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form>
            <textarea name="editor1" id="editor1" rows="10" cols="80">
                This is my textarea to be replaced with CKEditor.
            </textarea>
            <script>
                // Replace the <textarea id="editor1"> with a CKEditor
                // instance, using default configuration.
                CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1' );
            </script>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

It has the same behaviour (correct JS file is being loaded).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added all the important files and It's working now

Answer (score 0):

Check first that you have no error on javascript.

Check with firebug.

Comment: Seems there is no JS error :( Also, sample page is working.

Comment: Can you use the example js code of ckeditor documentation

Comment: Doesn't matter which code I'm using, sample is working but live is not.